# GEt value of column nodejs rest and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, collections, cursor

I am trying to obtain a column name value or multiple column name values but I am not obtaining it. I am pretty new to Nodejs but debugging it is even difficult. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient  = mongodb.MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Connected');

            var collection = db.collection('users');

            app.get('/db', function (request, response) {
                collection.find({username: request.query.username, password: request.query.password}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                        console.log(doc.toArray());
                        });
                    });
                });

        }
        db.close();
    });
```

I am basically authenticating if the username and password entered in db matches to my REST query and if yes then print success or redirect to a new page or something.

Comment: Do you get anything in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, unless you are actually expecting more than one "user" to share the same "username" and "password" then you are better off using [`.findOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne) for the singular response.

Then what is returned is just a plain JavaScript object, so just reference the properties:

```js
 collection.findOne(
    {
       username: request.query.username,
       password: request.query.password
    },
    function(err,doc) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log( doc.username );  // Just the username value
    }
 );
```

If course if "nothing" is returned and there is no "error" then you didn't match anything with your criteria, so either "username" or "password" is wrong.

That's as the basic excercise, but really, authentication is a wheel that was built long ago and you would likely be better of implementing an existing module to handle it.

And **get rid of `db.close()`**. The functions here are asynchronous and this will execute before anything else completes. You basically never want to call this in real world applications.

Comment: Well there is a possibility for a username to be same in the db.

Comment: @fscore Well you "should not" have that possibilty because in all systems using common sense a "username" would be unqiue. Neither is it desirable to have the same "username" "password" combination for two people since they would be able to accidently log into antohers account. I'm just showing you the basics here. `.find()` with `.toArray()` returns an array. Process "each" array element. `findOne()` is just a single object to start with. This is just learnning stuff. The Bus you should be riding here is "get an authentication package", which is also said.

Comment: I tried your code and get: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: @fscore What are you talking about? No response is being sent at all. Just logging to the console. Your code is trying to get an array from a plain object. I'm showing you a basic "how to do it" that you are currently getting wrong. This is not about writing the rest of your application for you.

Comment: so in that case I dont get anything on console either. I understand its not about writing the rest of my application but if your example does not work for me then you should be ready for feedback on that.

Comment: @fscore Read the answer. If you do not match a documen then nothing matches the "criteria" that is by design. What re you expecting to happen here? A plain text password you give in input to automatically match a hashed password in storage? Your inputs either basically do not match what is stored if you don't get a result. You were doing something wrong, I am showing you the right way to do it. Debugging your application and writing the rest is up to you. Write a small script with just the database actions first to learn those before jumping right in to other things.

Comment: Right I understand that.. But I have removed the password from the findOne block and the username that I am querying for does exists in my table but I still get nothing.

Comment: @fscore I don;'t think you understand at all. Open a mongodb shell, type in the query with your expected values and see what matches first. Then hardcode the values you are sure that match in your code. Then log the input you are sending in a request and so on. That is not my job. `.findOne()` and acessing the properties as shown is the correct way and what you asked. The rest is up to you.